# Android Dev: Logcat in Eclipse - can't restrict output to V/D/I/E?

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I'm using Logcat in Eclipse. I've been unable to find documentation online telling me as such, but presume that the V, D, I, E etc. buttons when clicked should restrict Logcat output to that pipeline? No matter which I select, every logcat output is spewed out, and it's making debugging nigh on impossible.

Can someone please tell me how to display only Debug output, i.e. Log.d(..) prints? I don't think this is possible using a filter, since I've tried creating one with log level 'Debug' and an empty tag and pid field, yet this simply prints all log outputs again.

Many thanks!

**UPDATE**

So, thanks to Aleadam's link below, I'm now aware that V/D/E/ etc. are 'priority levels' and include those priorities lower than themselves. It doesn't seem possible to restrict to only D(ebug) output, but at least I know how to restrict to D,V since V(erbose) is the only priority level lower than Debug:

```
adb logcat *:W
```

Of course, this must be done via the command line, so I'm now going to figure out how to employ the same strategy in Eclipse. The buttons really aren't working for me, I've no idea why, but it's frustrating!

Many thanks for all the information you've posted, guys.

Comment: From what I've understood log level filtering is inclusive. Meaning "error" is for error messages only. "warning" contains both "warning" and "error" messages. "info" includes both of the previous etc. Leaving you pretty much empty handed if you want to filter "debug" messages only as creating a filter with such log level will filter in higher level messages in any case. Adding pid and/or tag to your filter is the only way I'm aware of at least.

Comment: You're right, harism - I've just read the info at the link kindly posted by Aleadam below and updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Those buttons should work in the manner you're describing so long as they were logged with the appropriate API call in the Log class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Regexes/wildcards do not work. There's a bug I requested from almost a year ago. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11580&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: Indeed, earlier I tried a ' * ' and ' .* ' in the 'tag' with log level 'debug' in a filter, and that didn't work either. Frustrating.. thanks for the info Eric.

Comment: My pleasure. Sorry I can't be more help on the searches, but feel free to vote up that bug.

Comment: Sure thing - I've just done so, fingers crossed their engineers make it happen.

Comment: I'll twist their arms next week at I/O ;)

Answer (score 2):

adb logcat *:D will not show only debug, but everything with debug priority or higher.

For example, `adb logcat *:E > err.log` will save errors only.

For many options, check "Filtering Log Output" in here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat

If you're running under linux use grep. If you're on windows, use the shell: (e.g. `adb shell "logcat |grep 'D\/'"`)

Comment: Thanks for the 'nux tip, sadly I'm on Win 7 for this development and don't have Cygwin installed to take advantage of grep. EDIT: Aah, adb shell, gotcha.. will give it a whirl and return shortly, thanks!

Comment: @KomodoDave I was not clear enough. I meant adb shell. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering works on my system but I specify a Log Tag. This then creates a new button next to Log. So for Log Tag "QPR" I see [Log][QPR] buttons and when I press on [QPR] I only see logging that has been tagged as "QPR" as in Log.d(TAG,"onCreate",e);

At least on my system if I click on [Log] (E) I only get errors.

Hope that helps,
JAL

Comment: Thanks for the info, JAL - clicking on E gives me all the output, not just Errors. Bizarre, and frustrating.. at least I know now it's a bug and my intuition was correct!